# Where does the ObjectDataSource cache data?

Tags: asp.net, caching, viewstate, objectdatasource

I'm considering using an ObjectDataSource as an intermediate between my page controls and my data access layer & object model.  Traditionally I have manually created the object and populate it via a series of findcontrol statements when I need to insert/update data in the database.  I'm hoping that I can use the ObjectDataSource to marshal data between my object and my controls, eliminating that manual code, as long as the ObjectDataSource doesn't come with a lot of overhead.

I noticed the EnableCaching property, where does the caching occure?  is it in view state?

Comment: Which programming language are we talking about here??

Comment: sorry,  this refers to the .net environment (asp.net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It caches in the Global Cache: [ObjectDataSource.EnableCaching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.enablecaching.aspx)

Comment: Ok, so it's server side then.  Bah!  I was hoping for viewstate.

Comment: Would you really want to cache that much data in viewstate?